# Passing Python slice syntax around to functions

Tags: python, syntax, slice

In Python, is it possible to encapsulate exactly the common slice syntax and pass it around? I know that I can use `slice` or `__slice__` to emulate slicing. But I want to pass the exact same syntax that I would put in the square brackets that would get used with `__getitem__`.

For example, suppose I wrote a function to return some slice of a list.

```
def get_important_values(some_list, some_condition, slice):
    elems = filter(some_condition, some_list)
    return elems[slice]
```

This works fine if I manually pass in a slice object:

```
In [233]: get_important_values([1,2,3,4], lambda x: (x%2) == 0, slice(0, None))
Out[233]: [2, 4]
```

But what I want to let the user pass is *exactly* the same slicing they would have used with `__getitem__`:

```
get_important_values([1,2,3,4], lambda x: (x%2) == 0, (0:-1) )

# or

get_important_values([1,2,3,4], lambda x: (x%2) == 0, (0:) )
```

Obviously this generates a syntax error. But is there any way to make this work, without writing my own mini parser for the `x:y:t` type slices, and forcing the user to pass them as strings?

**Motivation**

I could just make this example function return something directly sliceable, such as `filter(some_condition, some_list)`, which will be the whole result as a list. In my actual example, however, the internal function is much more complicated, and if I know the slice that the user wants ahead of time, I can greatly simplify the calculation. But I want the user to not have to do much extra to tell me the slice ahead of time.

Comment: Where you wrote `__getattr__` I assume you mean `__getitem__`.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I'll edit to fix it above.

Comment: It would be kind of cool if Python had such a thing as "slice literals". I don't imagine it would be too hard to hack into the language but I imagine such a suggestion would be rejected as mostly unnecessary.

Comment: For `numpy` users, there is one more answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15162699/974555) using `numpy.s_`.

Comment: Is there a rejected PEP for this? I swear there was, but I can't find it now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Perhaps something along the following lines would work for you:

```
class SliceMaker(object):
  def __getitem__(self, item):
    return item

make_slice = SliceMaker()

print make_slice[3]
print make_slice[0:]
print make_slice[:-1]
print make_slice[1:10:2,...]
```

The idea is that you use `make_slice[]` instead of manually creating instances of `slice`. By doing this you'll be able to use the familiar square brackets syntax in all its glory.

Comment: This is a great idea. It's a lot cleaner than passing around the individual bounds of the slice. If I have to slightly burden the users of this with making their own slice input, I think this is the least intrusive of the suggestions so far.

Comment: Note that NumPy has this built in as `np.s_`: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html

Answer (score 2):

In short, no. That syntax is only valid in the context of the `[]` operator.  I might suggest accepting a tuple as input and then pass that tuple to `slice()`.  Alternatively, maybe you could redesign whatever you're doing so that `get_important_values()` is somehow implemented as a sliceable object.

For example, you could do something like:

```
class ImportantValueGetter(object):
    def __init__(self, some_list, some_condition):
        self.some_list = some_list
        self.some_condition = some_condition

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        # Here key could be an int or a slice; you can do some type checking if necessary
        return filter(self.some_condition, self.some_list)[key]
```

You can probably do one better by turning this into a Container ABC of some sort but that's the general idea.

Comment: How can I emulate the context of `[]`? Also, a tuple could work. But I don't like the need to distinguish between using None to imply (get everything) versus just leaving out that option. If `slice` took keywords, it might make it better.

Comment: Also, if I just wanted `get_important_values` to be directly sliceable, I would just return `filter(some_condition, some_list)` directly, which will be the whole result as a list. In my actual example, the internal function is much more complicated, and if I know the slice that the user wants ahead of time, I can greatly simplify the calculation. But I want the user to not have to do much extra to tell me the slice ahead of time.

Comment: You could still do that with this example.  In `__getitem__` if `key` is a `slice` (use `isinstance(key, slice)` then you can access all the start, stop, and step attributes of the slice object and manipulate them/optimize on them at will before applying it directly to the filter result.

Comment: I agree with you that I could do it this way, and this is a useful motif to keep in mind for other situations where this design fits a little better.

Answer (score 1):

One way (for simple slices) would be to have the slice argument either be a dict or an int,

ie

```
get_important_values([1, 2, 3, 4], lambda x: (x%2) == 0, {0: -1})
```

or

```
get_important_values([1, 2, 3, 4], lambda x: (x%2) == 0, 1)
```

then the syntax would stay more or less the same.

This wouldn't work though, for when you want to do things like

```
some_list[0:6:10..]
```