# Python: shorter syntax for slices with gaps?

Tags: python, slice

Suppose I want the first element, the 3rd through 200th elements, and the 201st element through the last element by step-size 3, from a list in Python.

One way to do it is with distinct indexing and concatenation:

```
new_list = old_list[0:1] + old_list[3:201] + old_list[201::3]
```

Is there a way to do this with just one index on `old_list`? I would like something like the following (I know this doesn't syntactically work since list indices cannot be lists and since Python unfortunately [doesn't have slice literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706258/passing-python-slice-syntax-around-to-functions); I'm just looking for something close):

```
new_list = old_list[[0, 3:201, 201::3]]
```

I can achieve some of this by switching to NumPy arrays, but I'm more interested in how to do it for native Python lists. I could also create [a slice maker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706258/passing-python-slice-syntax-around-to-functions) or something like that, and possibly strong arm that into giving me an equivalent slice object to represent the composition of all my desired slices.

But I'm looking for something that doesn't involve creating a new class to manage the slices. I want to just sort of concatenate the slice syntax and feed that to my list and have the list understand that it means to separately get the slices and concatenate their respective results in the end.

Comment: "Python unfortunately doesn't have slice primitives" Not even `slice`?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said slice literals, not slice primitives. That is, you can't just pass around the syntax `(0:10:2)` as if that was itself some object that always represented indices. You have to go through the tedious extra layer of making your own slice object, which destroys all the niceties of the slice syntax. See my [question that is also linked in the above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706258/passing-python-slice-syntax-around-to-functions).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A slice maker object (e.g. `SliceMaker` from your other question, or `np.s_`) can accept multiple comma-separated slices; they are received as a `tuple` of `slice`s or other objects:

```
from numpy import s_
s_[0, 3:5, 6::3]
Out[1]: (0, slice(3, 5, None), slice(6, None, 3))
```

NumPy uses this for multidimensional arrays, but you can use it for slice concatenation:

```
def xslice(arr, slices):
    if isinstance(slices, tuple):
        return sum((arr[s] if isinstance(s, slice) else [arr[s]] for s in slices), [])
    elif isinstance(slices, slice):
        return arr[slices]
    else:
        return [arr[slices]]
xslice(list(range(10)), s_[0, 3:5, 6::3])
Out[1]: [0, 3, 4, 6, 9]
xslice(list(range(10)), s_[1])
Out[2]: [1]
xslice(list(range(10)), s_[:])
Out[3]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: It doesn't work for ``xslice(list(range(10)), [1,2,3])``, nor does my latest revision. My first revision does.

Comment: @Dzhuang thanks! Improved your edit to test `insinstance(..., slice)`, swapping the latter 2 cases.

Comment: What if instead of a single index `0`, I have a list of indices like `[0, 2]`?

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
a = list(range(15, 50, 3))

# %%timeit -n 10000 -> 41.1 µs ± 1.71 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
[a[index] for index in np.r_[1:3, 5:7, 9:11]]
---
[18, 21, 30, 33, 42, 45]
```

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(15, 50, 3).astype(np.int32)

# %%timeit -n 10000 -> 31.9 µs ± 5.68 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
a[np.r_[1:3, 5:7, 9:11]]
---
array([18, 21, 30, 33, 42, 45], dtype=int32)
```

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(15, 50, 3).astype(np.int32)

# %%timeit -n 10000 -> 7.17 µs ± 1.17 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
slices = np.s_[1:3, 5:7, 9:11]
np.concatenate([a[_slice] for _slice in slices])
---
array([18, 21, 30, 33, 42, 45], dtype=int32)
```

Seems using numpy is a faster way.

Adding numpy part to the answer from [ecatmur](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15163014/4281353).

```
import numpy as np
def xslice(x, slices):
    """Extract slices from array-like
    Args:
        x: array-like
        slices: slice or tuple of slice objects
    """
    if isinstance(slices, tuple):
        if isinstance(x, np.ndarray):
            return np.concatenate([x[_slice] for _slice in slices])
        else:
            return sum((x[s] if isinstance(s, slice) else [x[s]] for s in slices), [])        
    elif isinstance(slices, slice):
        return x[slices]
    else:
        return [x[slices]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off writing your own sequence type.

```
>>> L = range(20)
>>> L
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
>>> operator.itemgetter(*(range(1, 5) + range(10, 18, 3)))(L)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 13, 16)
```

And to get you started on that:

```
>>> operator.itemgetter(*(range(*slice(1, 5).indices(len(L))) + range(*slice(10, 18, 3).indices(len(L)))))(L)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 13, 16)
```

Comment: I'd use `itertools.islice` and `itertools.chain` to construct these.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is "better", but it works so why not...

`[y for x in [old_list[slice(*a)] for a in ((0,1),(3,201),(201,None,3))] for y in x]`

It's probably slow (especially compared to chain) but it's basic python (3.5.2 used for testing)

Answer (score 0):

Why don;t you create a custom slice for your purpose

```
>>> from itertools import chain, islice
>>> it = range(50)
>>> def cslice(iterable, *selectors):
    return chain(*(islice(iterable,*s) for s in selectors))

>>> list(cslice(it,(1,5),(10,15),(25,None,3)))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 25, 28, 31, 34, 37, 40, 43, 46, 49]
```

Comment: Did you look at the link I included above to a previous question that I've asked? The answer to that question more or less embodies the same thing as your answer, but has better syntax and doesn't need `itertools`. The main goal of mine is to directly pass exactly the slice syntax as-is. Adding the syntactic overhead of representing slices as tuples and passing them to a new object is even worse than just concatenating separate slices.

Comment: @EMS: no, that answer just describe a way to create slices easily, but they can't be used as they are to index the elements in a list.
Abhijit solution does what you want, and you may combine it with the other answer to have a nice syntax like: `cslice(it, make_slice[1:5], make_slice[10:15], make_slice[25::3])`

Answer (score 0):

You could extend `list` to allow multiple slices and indices:

```
class MultindexList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if type(key) is tuple or type(key) is list:
            r = []
            for index in key:
                item = super().__getitem__(index)
                if type(index) is slice:
                    r += item
                else:
                    r.append(item)
            return r
        else:
            return super().__getitem__(key)


a = MultindexList(range(10))
print(a[1:3])             # [1, 2]
print(a[[1, 2]])          # [1, 2]
print(a[1, 1:3, 4:6])     # [1, 1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Comment: This is clever, but one of the main use cases would be passing "slices with gaps" to each component of a multi-dimensional quantity, so overloading getitem in such a way that the comma-separated values all applied to only the first dimension would not help.  I think the real issue is that slice syntax like `::2` or `3:8` don't represent literal objects, and there not built-in support for interval, range or set arithmetic on such literals.

Comment: @ely Indeed. Also I'm not sure if there is any standard semantics for what it means when a tuple or other sequence is passed as an index. e.g. it may be confusing that `numpy` uses them mainly for multidimensional indexing while here we use it for concatenating indices.