# Single slice getting elements from beginning and end of list in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, slice

The first and last N elements of a list in Python can be gotten using:

```
N = 2
my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(my_list[:N] + my_list[-N:])
# [0, 1, 4, 5]
```

Is it possible to do this with a single slice in pure Python?  I tried `my_list[-N:N]`, which is empty, and `my_list[N:-N]`, which gives exactly the elements I don't want.

Comment: _Avoid answering questions in comments._

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: shorter syntax for slices with gaps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842060/python-shorter-syntax-for-slices-with-gaps)

Comment: @dmitryro, It looks like you linked to a related question.  Is there an answer there you can link that you think answers how to do this?  I looked through and I see answers with external dependencies (like Numpy) or defining new classes.  I don't see any way to do this with a single slice.

Comment: In pure **Python** there's no way to do it otherwise but through relying on third party libraries or your own implementation.

Comment: There's, though, an approach using **itertools.islice** as it's mentioned in one of the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the builtin types, slices are by definition consecutive – a [slice represents a start, end and step between them](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice). There is no way for a single slice operation to represent non-consecutive elements, such as head and tail of a list.