# Slice syntax to object

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I have a class holding data (a numpy ndarray) that includes a method storing the data to a mat-file (using scipy.io.savemat). The data can be very large, so I may only want to store a segment of the data. Therefore I pass a slice-object, like this:

```
def write_mat(self, fn, fields=None, sel=None):
    # (set fields and sel to sensible values if None)
    scipy.io.savemat(fn, dict(data=self.data[fields][sel]))
```

Here, `fields` may be a list of strings (for `self.data` is a structured array), and `sel` is a slice-object. Of course, I cannot directly pass the slice-syntax into `write_mat`: `obj.write_mat(fn, fields, [::10])` is a SyntaxError. Of course, I can pass in `slice(None, None, 10)` instead, but I don't like this solution very much.

Is there any builtin convenience object that will allow me to create a slice-object from the slice-syntax? Of course, it's easy to implement:

```
In [574]: class Foo:
     ...:     def __getitem__(self, item):
     ...:         return item
     ...:     

In [578]: slicer = Foo()

In [579]: slicer[::100]
Out[579]: slice(None, None, 100)
```

but even for something easy to implement there may already be a more standard solution. Is there? By standard I mean existing inside Python, numpy, or scipy.

Comment: Because the accepted answer on the duplicate question doesn't mention it: you want `np.s_`, http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html

Comment: @ecatmur I think you can still answer that even when it's closed as a duplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer on [Passing Python slice syntax around to functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706258/passing-python-slice-syntax-around-to-functions) is correct, but as you're already using NumPy you can use [`np.s_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html):

```
import numpy as np
np.s_[1:2:3]
Out[1]: slice(1, 2, 3)
```