# Python lists: join list by index

Tags: python

I'd like to join a list into a string by index in Python 3.3. I can do it for items the follow each other, but I would like to access it by index only.

this works:

```
list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
partList = "".join(list[1:3])
-> BC
```

But how can I achieve this (it doesn't work):

```
list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
partList = "".join(list[0,3])
-> AD
```

Comment: Don't name variables over built-in names (such as `list`). You'll save yourself a lot of trouble.

Comment: `my_list[0:4:3]` works for this specific case, but is... unappealing. Any reason you specifically want a slice?

Comment: These two questions might be helpful: [question 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706258/passing-python-slice-syntax-around-to-functions) and [question 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842060/python-shorter-syntax-for-slices-with-gaps)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't slice lists into arbitrary chunks using [slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/2069350). Probably your best bet for the general case is to use a list of indices to build a list comprehension.

```
mylist = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] # the full list
indices = [0, 3] # the indices of myList that you want to extract

# Now build and join a new list comprehension using only those indices.
partList = "".join([e for i, e in enumerate(mylist) if i in indices])
print(partList) # >>> AD
```

As pointed out in the comments by **DSM**, if you're concerned with efficiency and you know your list of indices will be "friendly" (that is, it won't have any indices too big for the list you're cutting up), you can use a simpler expression without `enumerate`:

```
partList = "".join([mylist[i] for i in indices])
```

Comment: you could easily wrap this into a generator/function if you're looking for something more concise.

Comment: I think this is a rare case where `enumerate` doesn't add much; cf. `''.join([mylist[i] for i in indices])`.

Comment: @DSM That was actually the first thing I wrote, but I went with `enumerate` to allow for indices outside the length of the list (say, if some index list is being reused for slicing a bunch of different lists that may or not be of the same length for whatever reason).

Comment: With a list, though, you've made it an O(N^2) op [well, N*K] -- we could make `indices` a set, but then we lose the possibility for out-of-order access.  There's always `operator.itemgetter`, too.. ;^)

Answer (score 1):

What you are intending to perform is not slicing but selecting.

The closest possibility, I can think of is to use [operator.itemgetter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> mylist = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
>>> ''.join(itemgetter(0,3)(mylist))
'AD'
```

If you need to use a variable, then use a `splat` operator

```
index = (0,3)
''.join(itemgetter(*index)(mylist))
```

Comment: This looks what I am looking for. But I would like to use a variable for the indices '0,3' so that I can select any combination of indizes through a variable. I have tried: index = '0,3' or Index = [1,2] but the formula needs intividual integers separated by comma. I also would like to keep the number of indices flexible so that I could use 1,2,3 at another location. What would you suggest?